# GStreamer 1.0 on raspberry pi

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, raspberry-pi, rtsp, rtp

i'm trying to run gstreamer on rasp pi, but get this error:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0: GStreamer encountered a general resource error.
Additional debug info:
gstmultiudpsink.c(959): gst_multiudpsink_start (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0:
Failed to bind socket: Unable to create socket: Address family not supported by protocol
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

my config file is:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
TARGET=192.168.0.170
GST="gst-launch-1.0 -vv"
SRC=v4l2src
FIL1="video/x-raw,width=320,height=240,framerate=5/1"
ENC="rtpvrawpay"
DST="udpsink host=$TARGET port=13375"
PIPELINE="$SRC ! $FIL1 ! $ENC ! $DST"
$GST $PIPELINE
```

Please suggest what can be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, using the gstreamer packages from `http://vontaene.de/raspbian-updates/`. An upgrade to gstreamer through `apt-get` to version 1.0.9-1 resolved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable `ipv6` using this command:

```
modeprobe ipv6
```